# array of uint8_t and append data

Tags: c, arrays, string, uint8t

hi to all i have this problem i have a array of uint8_t

`uint8_t command_Text[256]`

i read some data from adc, i use snprintf for convert the data  float in uint8_t

```
` float aux;
uint8_t value[4];  
aux=(float)(HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc))
 snprintf(value,4,"%.0f",aux);   //convert the data float to uint8_t
 strcat(command_Text, value);   //append data `
```

i see this Warning argument of type "uint8_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char const *
i don't know manipolate the  string in uint_8 data, i want read data e to append  it in to array, can you help me?

Comment: snprintf takes a "char*" parameter, not "unsigned char*"

Comment: declare `value` as `char[4];`

Comment: That look slike for some embedded device. First rule is not to use flaoting point where avoidable. As your ADC most likely does not yield a floating point result, chances are pretty good you can use integers for the rest of your code, possibly emulating fractional or fixed-point arithmetics. Said that, you should also not use the `printf` and `scanf` family, as they are code-bloat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest something like:

```
uint8_t command_Text[256] = {'\0'};
....
uint8_t value[4] = {'\0'};  
snprintf(value,3,"%3.3u", atoi( HAL_ADC_GetValue( &hadc ) ) );   
strcat(command_Text, value);   //append data
```

Comment: who ever down voted this answer, please post a comment as to why the downvote.